# How to verify Microsoft Excel file identity and integrity using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a Microsoft Excel workbook (.xlsx format) that I plan to place it on our company website for customers to download and use it for applying a particular service to the Company.  I have password protected the workbook so that customers are not able to change its structure (They cannot delete, add, move, hide, unhide, or rename worksheets). Additionally, I have also locked read-only cells with a password so that customers are allowed to edit only those cells we intend to make as input cells.

Customers will send their filled application form using their pre-registered email address. Forms received from unregistered emails will be discarded. Received forms will be automatically read using Apache POI API.

However, for security reasons, we need to be able to verify that customers are sending exactly the same file as that we provided them for download and use. I know somebody can easily create a duplicate file looking exactly the same as our standard one, even without requiring cracking down our password protection.

I was wondering if there is any for Apache POI to verify that the excel file the customers are sending is exactly the same as the one we provided, with only editable (input) cells modified with inputs expected.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just read out only the values you expect/allow a customer to have changed, and copy those into a new copy of your template?

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr for your intelligent suggestion. However, I need to also make sure that what I am reading out is aligning to what was asked, as those forms are ultimately kept as evidence for a customer applying for that service. For example, if cellA1 asked user to input their firstName in cell B1, then I will obviously be interested in reading only B1. However, for form validity, I still need to ensure than cell A1 is intact. Hence the requirement. Will appreciate further suggestion

Comment: I think you'll need to loop over the sheets/rows/cells in your template, then check that every expected cell is the same in the user-supplied list, as well as checking that there are no extra sheets/rows/cells in the user one. It's probably ~100 lines of code, assuming you can easily tell which cells you were expecting the user to complete!

Comment: @Gagravarr. This makes sense. I think it's the quickly workable solution here. Again, thank you for your time. I will proceed with this solution

Comment: Write protected cells can be easily unprotected, if you want to make it a bit harder, you could read protect the file (I.e. pw on opening, e.g. using their email address)

Comment: @kiwiwings. Can you please give me some more elaboration on how I can read protect this. Remember that it's a public file and I want every registered customer to be able to download and fill it. There are a thousand of registered customers off course, each with their own email address. So, if I decide to read protect it, which password could I use such that all registered customers are able to open and write on its allowed cells?

Comment: @JohnWambura: instead of providing the same file on a static http folder, you could also provide a REST resource with a query parameter for the customer email address and encrypt the file on the fly. A normal .xlsx is actual a .zip file and the sheet xml can be edited and the protection attribute be removed. ... but read protecting it, is basically only a mitigation. you could even email them the customized .xlsx or when they send it back, have a poors man verification of the sender because of the matching password